# Have face-transitive polyhedra been completely classified?

Tags: dice, polyhedra

I've been researching polyhedral dice, and everywhere I look it states that face-transitive (and therefore fair) dice *include* polyhedra of various families, like the platonic solids, catalan solids, and trapezohedrons.

Is there a complete classification of face-transitive polyhedra? In other words, is there some proof that a face-transitive polyhedron must belong to one of a number of (possibly infinite) families?

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki: You could write that up as an answer.

Comment: Fair point! I've just converted it over.

Comment: For a direct list, the [Wolfram Mathworld page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Isohedron.html) might be a useful reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, the trapezohedrons *are* Catalan solids, in that their duals are 'Archimedean' in the sense of being fully vertex-transitive.  (Some classifications of the Archimedean (or equivalently, Catalan) solids exclude the prisms and antiprisms so that they can have a finite list of solids, but that's never made much sense to me.)  In any case, the two infinite families (prisms and antiprisms) and the well-known finite list of 'exceptional' solids are all that there are; there are no other infinite families.  I believe the proof of this shows up in [*The Symmetries of Things*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568812205) as a consequence of the classification of spherical symmetry groups.

Comment: Don't the isosceles tetrahedra provide another infinite family?

Comment: The prisms and antiprisms were excluded (or not found) by Archimedes himself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_solid#Origin_of_name. And their symmetry groups are "essentially 2D"; each operation is a 2D operation on $(x,y)$ (extended to 3D by leaving $z$ unchanged) possibly composed with a reflection $z\mapsto-z$. There's a single $z$-axis for the whole group.